# Continuosly running mocks while executing tests with Citrus Framework

Tags: citrus-framework

I need to write automated tests for Enterprise Service Bus (ESB). When ESB is running it performs different scheduled operations including DB queries, SOAP and TCP calls, etc. Also it periodically checks whether some services are active and stops flows in case it is not.

So in my case there will be some problems:

- some flows will stop because service is not responding
- another flows will continuously run in negative scenariuos producing errors

Is it possible to have mocks continuosly running while executing tests using Citrus Framework?

How else can I overcome this problems with Citrus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that all server components in Citrus do only live while tests are executed. This is because Citrus automatically starts and stops the server components before/after the test suite. When Citrus is inactive the server components are stopped.

If you want to break these limitations please have a look at the [citrus-simulator](https://github.com/christophd/citrus-simulator) side project which is a complete standalone simulator for different message transport types (still in beta phase though).

If the limitation mentioned before is Ok for you then you can use a combination of endpoint adapters on the server components in your Citrus project. You could have a static endpoint adapter that always sends a positive response for incoming health check requests.

Please see the documentation on endpoint adapters: http://www.citrusframework.org/reference/html/endpoint-adapter.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer! What do you mean by 'test suite'? 
For example in JUnit: Test Method, Test Class or A Set Of Test Classes specified in test run?

Comment: And also is there an API to control `citrus-simulator` behaviour then it is already running?
I don't understand how to use it for test automation without such functionallity.

Comment: I was referring to the complete set of test classes that are combined to a test suite run. Also citrus simulator is not capable of changing its logic at runtime. The simulator is defined with a set of predefined scenarios based on incoming request message content.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. Now I understand.

And the last thing to clear:
Suppose I added endpoint adapter which returns some default response while tests is running.. And in some test I need to change this behavior. For example, to check request coming to this endpoint and return not default response. Is it realy possible to do?

Comment: You can use a dispatching endpoint adapter that maps incoming requests to a processing logic (e.g. other endpoint adapters) based on some identifier on the request messages. The dispatcher evaluates a mapping key and decides which logic to apply for this request. Mapping keys can be evaluated with Xpath expression, request path, request method or header value.